# Gibberish text copied from PDF

Tags: fonts, encoding

I have a PDF converted/exported from Pages.app. When I copy text (English) from PDF and paste it in email/text editor/or Illustrator etc. the text appear to be gibberish (squares with cross and random symbols etc.) I cannot understand why I get these gibberish text as all my programs in my computer should have the same encoding and font.

Comment: Anything like - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61437/preview-copies-aliens-how-to-change-the-encoding-make-it-work ?